# Cosimulation in Gazebo Ignition - Setting link states

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-ignition, ignition-fortress

I am currently interested in running a cosimulation between Gazebo and Chrono since Gazebo has good support for sensor simulations and Chrono has very good vehicle models. So, in theory, Chrono could run the main simulation loop and update the physics (link states) of the car in Gazebo, while Gazebo, with deactivated physics, generates the sensor data. I sadly did not find any example of such a project. Does somebody know how I would start best? I had a look at the plugin system or the implementing an additional engine plugin, but that seems to involve much more scope than I intend to.